# What is the M320/GP30 LVG's use or purpose?

Tags: battlefield-3

This secondary/attachment was included with the CQ DLC.

From battlefield.wikia.com:

> Battlefield 3: Close Quarters Players who have access to the Close Quarters expansion pack can use this ammunition with their M320/GP30 launchers. Instead of detonating on impact (40mm Frag), the projectile uses a 3-second timed fuse. The blast and damage are comparable to a hand grenade, and kills are awarded as grenade launcher kills despite firing a grenade. The LVG inflicts little or no striking damage.

My question is:

What is the difference between this projectile and a standard, thrown grenade and the standard HE?

More specifically, does it:

- Have greater range?
- Have greater damage?

(I.e: What is the point, beyond 'more grenades'!)

Answer (score 5):

There has been several videos on youtube (Lvlcap has a review on the M320 LVG). The LVG is similar to throwing a grenade but to a greater distance. The damage is comparable to a grenade. This is useful for maps like Metro to clear out the side stairs without getting too close (at least for me). Lvlcap has a good review on it. Also, if you have the FRAG squad perk, I think you get 7 LVG nades

Comment: Haven't tested it for myself, but how about launching-time? I think the duration of throwing a default grenade will take longer then just fire a grenade with the M320 LVG. If so, then this is an advantage too :)

Comment: Yea there is a shorter delay with the LVG from what I experienced :D

Comment: Also, if you have the FRAG squad perk, I think you get 7 LVG nades.

Comment: @Streuner: This was the kind of thing I was wondering.

Comment: @nikeunltd If so, then add it to your answer :)

Comment: @Streuner alright

Comment: @nikeunltd - I believe it does launch, for all practical purposes, an M67 grenade with the SAME damage and kill radius. If you notice his question, he quotes this. From my experience, that is indeed true

Comment: From playing with it: it has a range that is 2-3 times that of a thrown grenade, and as stated has a damage 'comparable' to that of a grenade.  The point is that I _think_ this is the case but don't _know_ for sure.  The reason for asking the question was the vagueness of the Wikia article.  But +1 for the squad Frag bit @nikeunltd, I had forgotten that that boosts the M320 count as well.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted numbers, so I stopped being lazy and went to find out myself.

**Standing on a hand thrown grenade does 112 damage.**

[image: Standing Position]

[image: Damage]

**Prone on a grenade does the same (112)**

[image: Prone damage]

**Standing on an LVG does 107 Damage**
[image: LVG Standing]

**Prone on an LVG does 112**

[image: LVG Prone Damage]

While this is still only an assumption, it was the only logical conclusion I could come up with, as to the difference in prone versus standing LVG damage.

The LVG projectile is also a different model, looking like an M320 round.

**In summary:
The LVG does the same damage over a smaller area.**

Answer (score 1):

I would think the LVG grenade would be useful for hallways or tunnels where you know bad guys are but can't directly through a grenade at.  It will bounce off walls and such before blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

The M320 LVG is better used as a suppression tool. You will get greater suppression from the LVG than you would your regular M320.

Comment: This is the thing... If it has a smaller blast radius, does it make an effective suppression tool (at least, more so than a grenade...)?